# Generate keyspace system_schema cassandra

Tags: cassandra, schema, nodetool

I ran command `nodetool resetlocalschema` on my `cassandra` node. It is a two node cluster. 
Now `system_schema` is unavailable when I do a desc keyspaces.

How can I recreate `system_schema`.

Comment: Try restarting the node that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [nodetool resetlocalschema](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsResetLocalSchema.html.) indicates:

> The node temporarily loses metadata about the tables on the node, but rewrites the information from another node.

When you restart the cassandra service in the affected node, the issue will be fixed.